# Canopy Graphing and Randomization Errors

Tags: python

```
import math
import pylab as plt
import numpy
from numpy import sqrt
from scipy.integrate import quad
import random

numpy.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

#this integrates sqrt(1-x^2) from 0 to 1 and stores the value in q1area
def integrand (x):
return sqrt(1-x**2)
q1area, err = quad(integrand,0,1)

print "This program estimates the convergence of Pi to a ratio of one."

#code enters a while loop that runs until the user decides to exit the code (choice 4)
while True:
    print "Please choose from one of the five following options:"
    print " 1. 10^1\n 2. 10^2\n 3. 10^3\n 4. Exit"
    choice = int(raw_input())
    options = {1,2,3,4}

if choice == 1:
    #sets the x and y bounds on the graph
    plt.xlim([0,12])
    plt.ylim([-5,5])

    #sets the graph for the program to store random points on - sqrt(1-x^2)
    x = numpy.linspace(0,12,500)
    y = numpy.sqrt(1-x**2)
    #the program says that x and y need to be of the same dimension
    #if z doesn't have the x*0 term. That term seems to fix the error
    z = 1+x*0

    xcord = []
    ycord = []
    under = []
    above = []
    pratiolist = []
    yvalues = []
    xvalues = range(1,11)

    #appends a random point on the graph
    for i in range(10):
        xcord.append(random.random())
        ycord.append(random.random())

    #checks to see if the point is under or above the curve then assigns it to 
    #the corresponding list
    for j in ycord:
        if (j <= q1area):
            under.append(1)

        else:
            above.append(1)

        #defines two variables value as the length of a list
        punder = len(under)
        pabove = len(above)

        #checks for division by zero, adds one if true
        if pabove == 0:
            pabove = pabove + 1

        #calculates pratio as points above and below, creates list, appends values
        pratio = punder / float(pabove)
        pratiolist.append(pratio)

    #runs through pratiolist and calculates ratio to pi for each point
    for k in pratiolist:
        rtpi = k / float(math.pi)
        yvalues.append(rtpi)

    #displays graph
    plt.scatter(xvalues,yvalues,c='b')
    plt.plot(x,z,'g')
    plt.show()

if choice == 2:
    plt.xlim([0,120])
    plt.ylim([-5,5])

    x = numpy.linspace(0,120,500)
    y = numpy.sqrt(1-x**2)
    z = 1+x*0

    xcord = []
    ycord = []
    under = []
    above = []
    pratiolist = []
    yvalues = []
    xvalues = range(1,101)

    for i in range(100):
        xcord.append(random.random())
        ycord.append(random.random())

    for j in ycord:
        if (j <= q1area):
            under.append(1)

        else:
            above.append(1)

        punder = len(under)
        pabove = len(above)

        if pabove == 0:
            pabove = pabove + 1

        pratio = punder / float(pabove)
        pratiolist.append(pratio)

    for k in pratiolist:
        rtpi = k / float(math.pi)
        yvalues.append(rtpi)

    plt.scatter(xvalues,yvalues,c='b')
    plt.plot(x,z,'g')
    plt.show()

if choice == 3:
    plt.xlim([0,1100])
    plt.ylim([-5,5])

    x = numpy.linspace(0,1100,500)
    y = numpy.sqrt(1-x**2)
    z = 1+x*0

    xcord = []
    ycord = []
    under = []
    above = []
    pratiolist = []
    yvalues = []
    xvalues = range(1,1001)

    for i in range(1000):
        xcord.append(random.random())
        ycord.append(random.random())

    for j in ycord:
        if (j <= q1area):
            under.append(1)

        else:
            above.append(1)

        punder = len(under)
        pabove = len(above)

        if pabove == 0:
            pabove = pabove + 1

        pratio = punder / float(pabove)
        pratiolist.append(pratio)

    for k in pratiolist:
        rtpi = k / float(math.pi)
        yvalues.append(rtpi)

    plt.scatter(xvalues,yvalues,c='b')
    plt.plot(x,z,'g')
    plt.show()

if choice == 4:
    break

while choice not in options:
    print "Not a valid choice!\n"
```

Some of the white space is off, and I'm not really sure how to tab multiple lines. Anyway, this code takes 10, 100, or 1000 points and randomly asserts them over the graph of sqrt(1-x^2) between y = 0 and 1, and x = 0 and 1.

[image: graph of sqrt(1-x^2)]

It then takes a ratio of these points and compares it to the real value of Pi to get a convergence graph that will equal one (the more points to estimate, the better).

[image: pi ratio]

I'm having two issues. The first is probably pretty obvious...those points on the second graph are not as random as I would like. They seem to rise in a linear fashion and start over.

The second issue is that I want this code to loop and let the user select one of the three options over and over until they choose to exit. Each time, this should clear the graph and make a new one randomizing everything again. This is not the behavior I'm getting. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

For question 2: the reason for this is the way you calculate the ratio of points above to points below the curve. As `pabove` is incremented over time the ratio is changed in steps. With higher number of steps this should become less and less visible.
For question 1: see the code how to handle an endless input loop

Some remarks (many, many other hints in the code which follows):
- you seem to have omitted the commands to plot the random points (plot 1). I left the array definitions in the code which otherwise would be unused/superfluous.
- you compare a y-value to the integral `q1area`. This cannot be right if you only look at the dimensions (length to area). I have substituted the comparison to what it really should be - compare the point location (using x and y) to the points on the curve. The measure of the area below the curve `q1area` really is not used at all.

Here's my code proposition which I was not able to run or test as I don't have all the modules installed:

```
import math
import pylab as plt
import numpy
from numpy import sqrt
from scipy.integrate import quad
from random import random

### numpy.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

# function to integrate
def integrand (x):
    return sqrt(1-x**2)

# calculate integral with error estimate
q1area, error_estimate = quad(integrand, 0, 1)

print "This program estimates the convergence of Pi to a ratio of one."
pi = math.pi

while True:
    choice = 0
    options = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    while choice not in options:
        print "Please choose from one of the four following options:"
        print " 1. 10^1 steps\n 2. 10^2 steps\n 3. 10^3 steps\n 4. Exit"
        choice = int(raw_input())
    if choice == 4:
        break

    n = 10**choice # number of random samples

    # set the x and y bounds on the graph
    plt.xlim([0, 1.2*n])
    plt.ylim([-5, 5])

    # set the graph for the program to store random points on - sqrt(1-x^2)
    x = numpy.linspace(0, 1.2*n, 500)
    y = numpy.sqrt(1 - x**2)
    # x and z need to be of the same dimension
    # if z doesn't have the x*0 term. That term seems to fix the error
    z = 1 + x*0 # constant 1 over the range of x values

    xcoord = []
    ycoord = []
    pratiolist = []
    xvalues = range(1, n+1)
    yvalues = []

    # append n random points on the graph
    for i in range(n):
        xcoord.append(random())
        ycoord.append(random())

        # count if the point at (xcoord[i],ycoord[i]) is under or above the curve
        if ycoord[i] <= integrand(xcoord[i])::
            punder += 1
        else:
            pabove += 1

        # calculates pratio as points above and below, creates list, appends values
        if pabove > 0:
           pratiolist.append(punder / float(pabove))
        else:
           pratiolist.append(punder)

    # run through pratiolist and calculates ratio to pi for each point
    for k in pratiolist:
        rtpi = k / float(pi)
        yvalues.append(rtpi)

    # display graph
    plt.scatter(xvalues, yvalues, c='b')
    plt.plot(x, z, 'g')
    plt.show()
```

You will see that you don't have to use as many arrays as you started with, for instance for counting.
The main comparison is using the `integrand()` function so that you don't have to change the code if you change the function over which to integrate.

Comment: I'm getting a few errors here and struggling to follow the codes logic. The first error I'm getting is along like 56. Canopy says that punder is an int object that is not iterable.

Comment: I am assuming you refer to the code I've posted. Line 56 holds the main comparison statement. Besides, what exactly in my code needs more explanation?

Comment: Aside from it not working, nothing really. I see why it should work but it does not run.

Comment: Yes, although I modified several lines of your code and the code runs however, when the window for the graph pops up, it crashes immediately and the kernel must be restarted.

Comment: OK, if only the plot code is affected then try this: `1.2 * n` -> `int(1.2*n)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80227/discussion-between-user1016274-and-seeaemearohin).